# Custom Pattern Item in Android Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I was using the stroke pattern in Google Maps but was disappointed that there isn't a `new Arrow()` option. It seems that there's only `Dot`, `Gap` and `Dash` PatternItems. So my question, is it possible to create custom PatternItems, like the aforementioned arrow? So instead of the dots below, I would have an arrow head for each dot.

[image: map with stroke pattern]

Comment: did you find any solution to this.  i need to make my own pattern or at least be able to animate the Dot 90patternItem google provides.

Comment: @j2emanue nope, I ended up using the default ones. :(

Answer (score 0):

i achieved this but using a pathDashPathEffect. overrided the ondrawMap or something like that in the map view. if you have a mapfragment then you can easily add a view to the map . you have projections to get the start and end points for the line. look up pathEffect in androids paint class.